# Delete non-ascii characters from string? No special chars involved. Do not need to replace them

Tags: luatex, strings, ascii

After browsing, I see that this kind of question has been answered for other programming languages (R, Python, etc.) but not for TeX (specifically `lualatex`) The only related questions on this topic pertain to special characters, or string substitution, or non-utf8 encoding. So, MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} % Compile with lualatex.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\def\myname{Joseph “Jöey3” Xačengle}
\def\removenonascii#1{*this is what I ask*}
\begin{document}
\myname\par % expected: Joseph “Jöey3” Xačengle
\removenonascii{\myname}\par % expected: Joseph Jey3 Xaengle
\end{document}
```

All non-ascii characters have been deleted. Note that curly quotes are non-ascii (not even Latin-1). The lowercase oumlaut is Latin-1, but non-ascii. The ccaron is non-ascii, non-Latin-1. But I do not care whether anything is Latin-1, just ASCII. Encoding is utf8 throughout.

Argument to `\removenonascii` would be a macro that was already expanded to text. Since it is a macro, I cannot use verbatim, I should think.

I would use `\removenonascii{\myname}` as argument to another macro, which need not be defined here. The other macro is something I can program (I hope) if all input characters are ASCII.

One other thing: The input string (in this case, `\myname`) will have few non-ascii characters. In other words, I am working in the (primarily Western) European languages. But the `\StrSubstitute` or `\StrDel` functions of package `xstring` seem unsuited to the task, because there are a large number of possible non-ascii characters that might appear.

Comment: Are any macros to be removed as well?

Comment: @Skillmon No. The input to `\myname` is fully expanded, because the user would actually input text to something else, which would be expanded, then passed to `\myname` as a plain string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following uses `\text_purify:n` to first remove anything that's not a character (math mode would be untouched) while fully expanding expandable macros exhaustively. Then it steps over the result grapheme wise using `\text_map_function:nN` and forwards each grapheme to a function that tries to guess whether the following is valid ASCII.

As a decision rule the number of tokens is used (in pdfLaTeX anything that's two tokens is non-ASCII here), then if it's a single token, check that the character code is smaller than 128 (or else it's non-ASCII). This should work in all major engines.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \rallg_remove_non_ascii:n #1
  { \text_map_function:nN { \text_purify:n {#1} } \__rallg_remove_non_ascii:n }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \__rallg_if_ascii_range:n #1 { T }
  {
    \tl_if_single_token:nT {#1}
      {
        \int_compare:nNnTF { `#1 } < { 127 }
          \prg_return_true:
      }
    \prg_return_false:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__rallg_remove_non_ascii:n #1
  { \__rallg_if_ascii_range:nT {#1} {#1} }
\cs_new_eq:NN \removenonascii \rallg_remove_non_ascii:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\myname{Joseph “Jöey3” Xačengle}

\begin{document}
\myname\par % expected: Joseph “Jöey3” Xačengle
\removenonascii{\myname}\par % expected: Joseph Jey3 Xaengle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice use of the `expl3` text tools :)

Comment: You're gobbling spaces, which are ASCII.

Comment: @egreg yes, by the last edit, which wasn't thought through :) Thanks for pointing out, fixed that.

Comment: +1, but I don't like the unreadable optimizations in the code for the conditional.

Answer (score 2):

Here I use a token cycle.  Macros and grouping are also stripped out of the result, though if it were desired to retain them, that would be a simple change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\Characterdirective{\ifnum`#1<128\addcytoks{#1}\fi}
\Groupdirective{\processtoks{#1}}
\Macrodirective{}
\Spacedirective{\addcytoks{#1}}
\stripgroupingtrue
\newcommand\onlyascii[1]{\expandafter\tokencyclexpress#1\endtokencyclexpress}
\begin{document}
\def\myname{Joseph “Jöey3” Xačengle \textit{hi Möm}}
\myname

\onlyascii{\myname}

Note macros, braces gone: \detokenize\expandafter{\the\cytoks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As mentioned above, small adjustment will allow macros and grouping to be retained:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% use with pdflatex only
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\Characterdirective{\ifnum`#1<128\addcytoks{#1}\fi}
\Groupdirective{\processtoks{#1}}
\Macrodirective{\ifactivetok\else\addcytoks{#1}\fi}
\Spacedirective{\addcytoks{#1}}
\newcommand\onlyascii[1]{\expandafter\tokencyclexpress#1\endtokencyclexpress}
\begin{document}
\def\myname{Joseph “Jöey3” Xačengle \textit{hi Möm}}
\myname

\onlyascii{\myname}

Note macros, braces retained: \detokenize\expandafter{\the\cytoks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\ifnum...<128...\fi` test catches the non-ASCII characters when compiling in xelatex or lualatex, whereas the `\ifactivetok\else...\fi` test catches them when compiling in pdflatex.

Comment: Thanks. After looking at your replay and the one by Skillmon, I accepted his, because it more directly interacts with my other code (not shown here). But I think that your solution is more widely applicable to other users (upvoted). And, I am not a fan of expl3 syntax. :(